# How do I flatten the complexity of this select statement in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have the following table:

```sql
create table account_values
(
    account_id   bigint    not null,
    timestamp    timestamp not null,
    value1       numeric   not null,
    value2       numeric   not null,
    primary key (timestamp, account_id)
);
```

I also have the following query which produces an array of every value1+value2 of the row with the closest (before) timestamp to an evenly spaced generated series:

```sql
select array [(trunc(extract(epoch from gs) * 1000))::text, COALESCE((values.value1 + values.value2), 0.000000)::text]
from generate_series((now() - '1 year'::interval)::timestamp, now(), interval '1 day') gs
         left join lateral (select value1, value2
                            from account_values
                            where timestamp <= gs and account_id = ?
                            order by timestamp desc
                            limit 1) equity on (TRUE);
```

The issue with this method of generating such an array becomes apparent when inspecting the output of `explain analyse`:

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.45..3410.74 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=0.134..3948.546 rows=366 loops=1)
  ->  Function Scan on generate_series gs  (cost=0.02..10.02 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.075..0.244 rows=366 loops=1)
  ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..3.36 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=10.783..10.783 rows=1 loops=366)
        ->  Index Scan Backward using account_values_pkey on account_values  (cost=0.43..67730.27 rows=23130 width=26) (actual time=10.782..10.782 rows=1 loops=366)
"              Index Cond: ((""timestamp"" <= gs.gs) AND (account_id = 459))"
Planning Time: 0.136 ms
Execution Time: 3948.659 ms
```

Specifically: `loops=366`

This problem will only get worse if I ever decide to decrease my generated series interval time.

Is there a way to flatten this looped select into a more efficient query?
If not, what are some other approaches I can take to improving the performance?

edit;

One hard requirement is that the result of the statement cannot be altered. For example I don't want the range to round to the closest day. The range should always start the second the statement is invoked and each interval precisely one day before.

Comment: Adding the following index helped improve performance:
`CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_account_values_account_timestamp ON account_values (account_id, "timestamp");`

Comment: Note: the COALESCE() is not needed; both value1 and value2 are not NULLable.

Comment: What is the reason for casting to text and packing into an array?

Comment: @wildplasser That's simply the format the ingesting system requires

Comment: COALESCE is required, as there is no guarantee that the left join produces a result for every timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

based on Edouard answer.

```
   with a(_timestamp,values_agg) as
(select _timestamp, array_agg(lpad( (value1 + value2)::text,6,'0')) as values_agg from account_values
where account_id = 1
and _timestamp <@tsrange(now()::timestamp - '1 year'::interval, now()::timestamp)
group by 1)
select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object
    (
    '_timestamp', trunc(extract(epoch from _timestamp) *1000)::text
    , 'values', values_agg )
    ) AS item from a;
```

Comment: Your answer has a few syntax errors.

Comment: After solving them I'm stuck on: `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "a"`

Comment: After solving that, I see this answer doesn't maintain the same output as the original query. The issue is that it doesn't specify a constant interval to group the results to, so way too many rows are returned.

An acceptable solution should return as many rows as there are days in the current year, with the timestamps decrementing from Now() in interval 1 day for column one. The second column must be the sum of value1+value2 of the first record BEFORE the timestamp in column one, using 0.0 if no record is found.

Comment: @vddox updated my answer. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure you will get the exact same result, but it should be faster :

```
select array [ (trunc(extract(epoch from date_trunc('day', timestamp)) * 1000))::text
             , (array_agg(value1 + value2 ORDER BY timestamp DESC))[1] :: text
             ]
  from account_values
 where account_id = ?
   and timestamp <@ tsrange(now() - '1 year'::interval, now())
 group by date_trunc('day', timestamp)
```

Comment: I'll have to see if I can alter your solution to produce the same output as my original statement. It's a hard requirement that the interval boundaries start at the exact time the query is executed and don't truncate to the nearest day boundary.

Comment: FYI your solution contains a syntax error.

Comment: the `array_agg` function must be within brackets, or is it another syntax error ?

Comment: That was one, needing to cast the types inside tsrange to timestamp was need also.

After executing there was a slight performance improvement with this solution, however the output isn't close to the same which is a requirement (added it to original question as an edit).

Comment: can you share the explain analyse of my solution please ?